# Mathematica algorithms made possible with Wolfram's NKS?

Tags: algorithm

In Wolfram's [NKS](https://www.wolframscience.com) he mentions that the Rule-30 Cellular Automata is used as a random number generator in Mathematica. What other algorithms in Mathematica have been made possible with Wolfram's NKS?